# CASE expression that does NOT have short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: sql, sqlite, case, short-circuiting

I recently began teaching myself (terrible) SQLite.  One thing that struck me as annoying was the CASE expression, namely the fact that it employs short-circuit evaluation.

Is there any way to get around this?  I am looking for a CASE statement that does not employ short-circuit evaluation.

```
UPDATE [table]SET [counting_column] =

(
CASE
    when [column1] = NULL 
    then [counting_column] + 1

    ...

    when [column31] = NULL
    then [counting_column] + 1
end
)
```

I would like each entry in the database to be tested by each case statement, not just the first one that evaluates to true.  Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: I apologize if there's some glaring error-- I'm quite new at this so go easy please.

Comment: Could you give an example where you need non-short-circuit evaluation?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do -- you can have multiple cases inside of each other if needed...  Sample data, desired results -- perhaps we could help.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I edited my question to be more specific, sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed just adding 1 to `counting_column` for each condition that is met, you can use a chain of *n* `CASE` statements and add the results together.  Each individual `CASE` supplies a `0` or `1`, all of which are added together and added to the current value of `counting_column`.

```
UPDATE [table] SET [counting_column] =
(
  [counting_column] + 
  (CASE when [column1] IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  (CASE when [column2] IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    ...
    ...
  (CASE when [column30] IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  (CASE when [column31] IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END)
)
```

Note that I have changed the `= NULL` to `IS NULL`.  `NULL` is a special non-value that cannot be compared with an equality `=`.

I'll also point out that although `[]` enclosed identifiers are ok in SQLite, this is mostly for compatibility with T-SQL.  The more standard approach is to use double-quotes as in `UPDATE "table" SET "counting_column" = ...`

Comment: Thanks much, that is indeed all I am doing and it worked great.  Like I said, I'm not very good at this, so that's why I couldn't do it.